# Change Ports in MAMP and Apache won't start (Mac)

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp

I am using MAMP 3.2.1 on Mac OS X 10.9.5 and trying to change my Ports so I can go to localhost/... instead of localhost:8888/... in my browser.

When I go to change the ports in Preferences the option I have is "Set Web & MySQL ports to 80 & 3306", however when I do this, the Apache server does not restart.

I have seen other posts that say rename envvars to __envvars but mine is called envvars_ so I'm guessing that's irrelevant.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why doesn't the Apache server start? Does it give any error messages?

Comment: I don't see any error messages - I haven't used MAMP before but I have changed my php.ini files to display_errors = On and still nothing. Sorry I know this is probably a real newb question.

Answer (score 23):

This is rather older post but I faced the same issue today. As it turned out there was already one more Apache running on port 80 and was clashing with the new MAMP port setup. Hopefully this will help you:

1. Setup ports to 80 (Apache), 81 (nginx) and 3306 (mysql) in your MAMP configuration.
2. Quit your MAMP
3. From CLI type `sudo apachectl stop`
4. From CLI type `ps -A | grep httpd` and you shouldn't see any running process (apart from your grep)
5. Start your MAMP (at this point MAMP should start Apache since 80 port is not in use)

Comment: super solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the instruction bellow, it worked for me.

1.Open Activity Monitor program and select "All Processes" 
2.Search for "mysqld" in the search area. You might see an example of mysql running 
3.hit quit process. 
4.Restart MAMP and it will fix all.

Comment: Thanks - just followed your instructions but unfortunately, Apache server is still not running.

Comment: How about MySql and others ?

Comment: MySQL server runs fine. The settings it gives me are Apache 80 Nginx 80 and MySQL 3306. If I use the default Mamp ports everything works perfectly.

Comment: Some ports are in use by default.Make sure the port number you are putting, does not overlap them.

Comment: The OP is complaining about Apache not getting started, not sure if killing `mysqld` helps in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When you have installed MAMP, before starting it, change the port to 80 & 3306, then it will work properly. Once you start it with default port and then stopping it and changing port raises this issue.